# How to set value for atribute from directive | Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I have HTML component `<p-calendar appLocalization="awdwa" [locale]="calendarUa"></p-calendar>`

There I have my custom derective `appLocalization`. Code of Derective

```html
@Directive({
    selector: '[appLocalization]'
})
export class LocalizationDirective implements AfterContentInit, OnInit {
    @Output() appLocalizationChange: any;
    @Input() public appLocalization: string;

    public constructor(
        private el: ElementRef) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.el.nativeElement.attributes.locale = calendarUa;
        console.log(this.el.nativeElement.attributes.locale);
    }
}
```

Next in derective a will know what data I need to set for attribute `locale`. Locale is not my attribute. It is a attribute of `p-calendar.`

As you can see I try to get this - `this.el.nativeElement.attributes.locale` in my derective. But it is undefined. There You can see the attributes of element. I cant do `this.el.nativeElement.attributes.ng-reflect-locale = calendarUa;` Cuz it is mistake in console. How I can set the value fro other attribute from my custom derective?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If p-calendar is a component, it is not an attribute but an `@Input`. You need to inject it into your directive:

```js
public constructor(
  @Inject(ThatPCalendarComponent) private readonly pCalendar: ThatPCalendarComponent) {
}
```

And then do `this.pCalendar.locale = whatever`

Comment: I think `@Inject` is not required here otherwise LGTM

Comment: I often use tokens, I don't want to think whether I need it or not, whether I compile with `emitDecoratorMetadata` or not or whatever else is affected by it. I just write it all the time, it doesn't take space in the resulting bundle anyway.

Comment: It will be great but only what I have its CalendarModule from primeNg. It cant set a value by @Inject. -calendar it isnot my attribute

Comment: @FX_Sektor I would say you also have `import {Calendar} from 'primeng/calendar';`

Comment: @waterplea I will set such right! but I set the value for local in private calender: Calendar. It is work and chage parametr for calender where derective is on. Thanks